# Probability that a team wins

Tags: probability

The chance that a team wins a game when loosing 3+ turnovers is 13.3% if their opponent is not the Lakers. If
their opponent is the Lakers, the percentage of winning is 24%.

There are 30 teams in total. What is the likelihood of a team winning a game
if their opponent is **not** the Lakers.

I have done the following: 
P(Playing not the Lakers) = 28/29 or .9655 
P(Playing the Lakers) = 1/29 or .0345
 P(Win | Playing the Lakers) = .133
 P(Win | Not the Lakers) = .24
However, now that I calculated these values, I am unsure of where to go with them. Any help or elaboration would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use Bayes theorem. If you don't know it, google it.

Comment: Does this make sense?  Suppose the Spurs are playing the Clippers.  They can't both have a $13.3\%$ probability of winning.

Comment: Well, I see the edit so the set up makes sense...but there isn't enough information.  To make progress we'd need to know the probability of turning the ball over at least three times.  Note:  post edit, your conditional probabilities are not accurate (they weren't accurate before either, but then they just looked interchanged).

Comment: Sadly, this is all of the information I have been given. Would it be possible to apply Bayes thrm. For example, let A = "team wins a game when loosing 3+ turnovers" and B = "Play a team that's not the Lakers"? So it would be something like, ((.133)(.373))/.9655

Comment: I don't see how.  Should we assume that every team is equally likely to turn the ball over?  Is this meant to happen a lot or seldom?  (can't happen too often or that $13.3\%$ won't be possible).  Sorry.

Comment: Being that this is all of the information I have been given. I am assuming all teams are equally likely. Regardless of what team, if they loose 3+ turnovers their winrate is now 13.3%. I know it is unlogical but I am just trying to work something out of it.

Comment: Ok, if you are allowed to string together a lot of assumptions maybe it's possible...I'll write something and post it below.  No guarantees.

Comment: Sorry...I had an idea, but it went nowhere.  still seems to me I need some information about the probability of making a lot of turnovers.  I don't see any way to establish a god prior for that.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be worth pointing out:  If you want to make purely neutral assumptions (so that every non-Laker team has equal probabilities wherever that makes sense) then the answer is $.5$

The turnovers, from this point of view, are a red herring.  Team $A$ has some chance of making a lot of turnovers and $B$ has an equal chance.  The cases where one does and the other doesn't cancel out.  The cases where either both do or both do not make a lot of turnovers must, by neutrality, be decided with probability $.5$

No idea if this is what was intended, but perhaps it is worth pointing out.

Comment: This makes sense. Definitely not a great problem, but I thank you for sticking with me on this one!

Comment: Well, I hope it helps!